# Implement user friendly routes in angular 4 application

Tags: angular, routes

I have an angular 4 Single Page application. Marketing demand is to check if we can have urls like this:

www.abc.com/fancyname/x

www.abc.com/fancyname/y

www.abc.com/fancyname/z

Currently the routes displayed are: 
www.abc.com/#/x and so on.

How can the above be implemented and how do we configure the route?

- Progress till now:

a) To remove the # we can use the pathlocationstratergy but we need to try the same. Haven't tried till now

b) We can use the childrouting but we might  not have enough time in hands as current routing is not done in such a manner.

Currently our routing is done as:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'x', component: xComponent },
  { path: 'y',      component: yComponent},
  { path: 'z',      component: zComponent},
];

we want it to be like: 

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'fancyname/x', component: xComponent },
  { path: 'fancyname/y',      component: yComponent},
  { path: 'fancyname/z',      component: zComponent},
];
```

We assume if we try to implement something like fancyname/x it will be considered as child routing. We cannot manipulate the base-href as /fancyname as it will break the urls for all internal assets like images, fonts etc.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you should just use a componentless parent route.

Like so:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{ 
  path: 'fancyname', 
  children: [
    { path: 'x', component: xComponent },
    { path: 'y', component: yComponent },
    { path: 'z', component: zComponent }
  ]}
];
```

As far as I'm aware, doing it this way shouldn't change anything functionally in your app, besides making the routes "fancyname/childpath".

Comment: Thanks. I had to add some base href as well. Did the same along with some backend configuration to achieve the result.